# Open set in LF-space

Tags: functional-analysis, topological-vector-spaces

Assume $E_1\subset E_2\subset ...$ is a sequence of Frechet spaces, each one embedded in the next.
Let $E$ be their union, and one puts the LF topology on $E$.

I wished one can say the following: **If $U\subset E$ satisfies that for every $k$, $U\cap E_k$ is open in $E_k$, then $U$ is open in $E$.**

But from the definition, one needs to show that for each $x\in U$, there is a balanced, convex set $W$ such that $x+W\subset U$, and $W\cap E_k$ is open for every $k$. Just from the information that $U\cap E_k$ is open it seems difficult to find such $W$. So is the above statement even true?

Comment: The LF-topology is the finest *locally convex* topology on $E$ making all inclusions continuous. A *convex* set is open if all intersections are open but you should not expect this for non-convex sets.